# Example of How to Enter minSize=0 in a Log4J2 Properties File

Tags: java, log4j2

I see the syntax for entering this in a XML property file for Log4J2 -- "OnStartupTriggeringPolicy": {"minSize":"0"}

How would you enter this in a properties file?

Answer (score 0):

In a properties file you have lines of the shape 'key=value'.
In your case you need something like

```
xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.minSize=0
```

where I am not sure what the `xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxx` has to be replaced for.